# Ширина столбца в PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

спасайте, потому, что это хаос блин.

Есть файл excel, в нем акт выполненных работ, с табличкой наименования этих работ. Задача стоит такая, этот файл я использую как шаблон, потом в php подставляю в него нужные данные через библиотеку PhpSpreadsheet и сохраняю как мне нужно. Проблема в том, что ширина первого столбца таблицы после сохранения меняется. Сохраняю в html, там она уже шире (прикреплю скрины). В коде никак не задаю ни ширину, ни другие параметры форматирования. В итоге получаю неадекватно широкую первую колонку. Может кто знает в чем проблема, и как сделать первую колонку такой же как и в самом документе?

Скрин исходного файла excel:

[image: Скрин исходного файла excel]

Результат таблицы, когда сохраняю в html:

[image: Результат таблицы, когда сохраняю в html]

Сам код:

```
        $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReaderForFile($inputFileName);

        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $sheet->setCellValue('D4', 'работ № '.$id);

        /*
           Другие $sheet->setCellValue
        */

        $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Html($spreadsheet);
        $writer->setUseInlineCss(true);

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="act.html"');

        $writer->save("php://output");
```

Comment: Решилось тем, что переписал заново структуру файла excel, все поправилось, где именно был глюк не удалось найти

Answer (score 0):

[установка ширины столбца](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-a-columns-width)

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(12);
```

Comment: Да, пробовал, это не помогло. Переписал заново структуру файла excel, все поправилось, где именно был глюк не удалось найти